# Is number "8" topologically equivalent to a circle in the 2D space?

Tags: homotopy-theory, geometric-topology

We may treat the cross point of number "8" is just an overlap of two lines (instead of a "melting" point of two lines, so that it is not treated as two connected circle). To make it clear, for example, suppose we have a rope which are connected as a circle. Now I rotate part of the circle to make it a "8".

The question is, does this kind of "8" topologically equivalent to a circle in the two dimensional space?

We may say it is homeomorphic to a circle, because we can smoothly move from one to another. But I think they are still not equivalent in 2D because to *smoothly* change number "8" to a circle, we also need to rotate half part of "8" in the vertical direction. And the vertical motion is outside the the 2D, and is not allowed within the two dimensional space. Am I right?

Comment: What is a knot point?

Comment: @TonyK I mean it is not the cross point so that it is not treated as two connected circles. It's just the overlap of the two lines.

Comment: "Overlap of two lines" is also disallowed in 2d space. So since we're already using the third dimension, what's wrong with using it a bit more?

Comment: @Arthur Yes, you are right. This question is from the idea of winding number. If we wind the origin two times, we get the winding number 2, the winding line of must have some overlaps on itself.  I think this winding line should have a different topology from the circle, because they have the different winding number.

Comment: @Xliu When working with winding number, you have important extra information; those curves are _functions_, not just figures in the plane. The standard figure-8 doesn't have such information associated with it, and thus the two crossing lines "melt into" one another. If you do decide to parameterize the figure-8, then it is indeed homotopic to a circle in the plane.

Comment: @Arthur this make sense. Thank you!

Comment: Your requirement that the crossing point is not a single point in $\Bbb R^2$ basically makes your question meaningless. You are no longer in $\Bbb R^2$ when you do that.

Comment: @Arthur: Unlike X liu, I can't make sense of the last sentence of your latest comment.

Comment: @TonyK The best way I know of to make the figure-8 behave the way X liu wants (as far as I can tell) is to parametrize it. This makes the two lines that cross "distinguishable". But a function $S^1\to \Bbb R^2$ that traces out a figure-8 is homotopic to a function $S^1\to \Bbb R^2$ that traces out a circle. Which is to say, you can indeed "straighten out" the figure-8 into a circle in that case. It won't be regular, thoguh. Which might be a way to formalise what the OP means with "to smoothly change number "8" to a circle, we also need to rotate half part of "8" in the vertical direction."

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you are thinking of the diagram '8' as a knot diagram: take your rope in $\mathbb{R}^3$, twist it once, and then *project down onto $\mathbb{R}^2$*. The result, which you can view as the symbol '8' (with a notion of over-under at the center point), is not itself homeomorphic to $S^1$, but the original knot certainly is.

So viewing the number '8' as a wedge of two circles is certainly not homeomorphic to $S^1$, but viewing it as a 4-valent graph with one vertex and two edges, as well as the information about overcrossing/undercrossing at the vertex, we get the standard 1-crossing diagram of the unknot.

However, as you note, this 'over-under' information encodes something that doesn't occur in the projection onto our page ($\mathbb{R}^2$), but occurs with our rope in space ($\mathbb{R}^3$).

Answer (score 1):

This really has nothing to do with $3$d or $2$d space.

If you remove any one point from a circle, the remaining space is connected.

That is not true for all points in the figure $8.$ Specifically, if you remove the cross point from the space, you end up with a space with two components.

Comment: Suppose we have a rope which are connected as a circle. Now I rotate part of the circle to make it a "8".  For this "8", if you remove any one point, or make a cut, the cut rope can smoothly be moved into an open circle - the remaining space is connected.

Comment: @Xliu when you make the circle into the shape of an 8 then you equivocate two distinct points on the circle into a single point. Removing that point will still disconnect the rope so the embedding space remains irrelevant.

Comment: @CyclotomicField Exactly. That's why I strengthen it is an overlap and the 3D is involved.

Comment: The eight is not a rope loop with two points at the center. It is one point at the center. @Xliu

Comment: @ThomasAndrews That's your "definition" of "8". Just image how you write "8", do you cross the point two times? In fact, I have no problem of on the '8' based on this definition. My question is: if we treat "8" as the 'overlap', what will happened?

Comment: This is a case where you might want to start learning the more formal definitions. There’s intuition, but intuition can fail without the proper grounding in some elementary set theory and continuous functions. In a set, a point can be in the set at most once. In $\mathbb R^n,$ if the distance between two points is zero, then they are the same point. @Xliu

Comment: So there *is* a continuous map from a circle onto an $8$ (your notion of a rope,) but the function is not “one-to-one.” @Xliu

Comment: But sure, if you want to define things differently from every mathematicians, you might get different results. But your definitions are going to be much harder. I can define a topological $8$ as the set of points $(x,y)$ where either $x^2+(y-1)^2=1$ or $x^2+(y+1)^2=1$ or both. @Xliu

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Yes, we do have the "one-to-one" problem. But I think this "one-to-one" problem of the overlap point can be ***dealt*** when we treated it as overlap of "multipoints", each point is identified by it's own function. Mathematically, a point is not necessarily identified by the position; any property can be used to identify a point from another.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews For example when we draw a pentagram(the function is simpler). The cross point happens when two lines cross. We can then treat the crosspoint as the overlap of two points, each point is corresponding to one line (it is a little weired, but it is not a problem when we treat it in 3D). We may then discuss the homeomorphism of it to a circle.

Comment: No, we can’t count the cross points as two points. You might think that’s the case, but that is not how topologist’s (or mathematicians in general) define it.  What is the subset of $\ma5bb R^2$ which is your pentagram? Sets contain elements only once. If you want something different, then you want to study something other than topology. Topology’s intuition is a good start, but you can’t get anywhere in math without careful definitions. You seem to have made up your mind about things, so I’m done trying to explain. Under usual definitions, 8 is different than 0, and I have shown why. @Xliu

Answer (score 0):

No, they are not topologically equivalent. The fundamental group of the circle is the group $\mathbb{Z}$ of integers, and that of 8 is the free group on two symbols.

Comment: When say "8 is the free group on two symbols", do we treat "8"  as two connected circles (at one point), or the cross point just means a overlap of two lines? Seems that they are the different topological figure?

Comment: @Xliu, there is no such thing as "just an overlap of two lines". If two lines overlap, they have a common point.

Comment: @Xliu You are asking for two points with the same $x$ and $y$ coordinates. That makes them equal in two dimensions.

Comment: @JohnDouma Partly agree with you about the fact, if we stick with the point identified by the position. The question is: can we define the degeneracy of points in 2D? Personally I think it's fine, as it is not necessary to identify two points by only the position, we may use any additional property to identify them.  For example the cross point of two lines. We may think the cross point is the overlap of two points, each point is identified by it's own line function.  And this definition is within 2D, we dont need additional dimension to do it.

Comment: @Xliu The additional property would constitute another dimension. Imagine if we colored the points red and green. Then a point would be identified by two location points and a color. That is no longer two dimensional.

Comment: @JohnDouma Yes. You are right, a dimension with discrete values.

Answer (score 0):

They are not the same and you don't need winding numbers nor do you need fundamental groups.

There are two relevant facts:

1. A continuous function remains continuous if its domain is restricted.
2. Continuous functions take connected sets to connected sets.

If there was a homeomorphism from the circle to the figure eight, some point of the circle, call it $p$ gets mapped to the cross point on the figure eight. Remove that point from the domain. Then the homeomorphism would take the circle minus one point to the figure eight but, since the circle with a point removed is connected, the entire domain must be mapped to a connected component of the figure eight minus a point. Since that object is not connected the function can no longer be surjective so it could not have been a homeomorphism.

Comment: When you treated the cross point as the cross of two lines, the cross point is in fact the overlap of two lines. Suppose we have a rope which are connected as a circle, We can  rotate part of the circle to make it a "8" (Th). If we treat "8" in this way (In fact, this is the way we write "8") , you can find homeomorphism from the circle to the figure "8".

Comment: An overlap is different. We can twist a circular rope into a figure eight and it is still homeomorphic to a circle but we cannot do that in two dimensions.

Comment: Yes. This is the situation I want to ask.

Comment: @Xliu If you twist a circle into a figure eight it is still topologically a circle. If that is what you meant you may want to edit your question because I believe I am not the only one that misunderstood.